# Printer is printing green where it should be black

Tags: printing, printer, inkjet-printer

My HP Envy 4520 printer (model F0V69A) is printing green where it should be black.

What it prints as:

> [image]

What it should look like:

> [image]

Ink levels are good, pictured below.

What can I do to diagnose/repair?

[image]

Comment: Seeing how the quality isn’t great either, the print head is probably causing this. I’m not familiar with your printer though.

Comment: If its a laser printer, it could be fuser or drumunit that is damaged.

Comment: [Printer printing green tint](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Printer-Ink-Cartridges-Print-Quality/Printer-printing-green-tint/td-p/8318289) on the HP website says ``Prints that appear more green are commonly caused by an absence of magenta ink/toner being put to paper by your printer``. Sine the estimated ink levels look OK, maybe try the suggestion from that HP website of cleaning the ink cartridges. I haven't checked how that is done on the HP Envy 4520.

Comment: What happens if you go to the Printing Preferences and select Paper/Quality > Black & White? Does it then print black?

Answer (score 3):

- Try the [Printer Status Report](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04707093):

  1. Load plain white paper.
  2. On the printer control panel, swipe the display to the left
  3. Touch **Setup**.
  4. Touch **Tools**.
  5. Swipe up on the display.
  6. Touch **Print Status Reports**.

  In particular, four distinct bars should be printed, with the right a solid *black*.
- Download the [HP Envy 4520 User Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04778353.pdf), and on p. 52, follow, step-by-step, **Fix print quality issues**. In particular, see directions **To clean the cartridges from the printer display** on p. 55, and then **print a test page** (p. 56).